# Drawing a ball in the center of the image with Python itk

Tags: python, image-processing, itk

```
import itk
ImageType = itk.Image[itk.UC, 3]
newimage = ImageType.New()
size = itk.Size[3]()
size = [100, 100, 80]
index = itk.Index[3]()
index = [0, 0, 0]
region = itk.ImageRegion[3]()
region.SetSize(size)
region.SetIndex(index)
newimage.SetRegions(region)
newimage.Allocate()
newimage.FillBuffer(63)
origin = itk.Point[itk.D, 3]()
origin = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
spacing = itk.Vector[itk.D, 3]()
spacing = (0.40, 0.40, 1.0)
newimage.SetOrigin(origin)
newimage.SetSpacing(spacing)
writer = itk.ImageFileWriter[ImageType].New()
writer.SetInput(newimage)
writer.SetFileName('wynik3.nii')
writer.Update()
```

I have this code and I need to draw a light gray ball with a radius of 31 in the center of the image but I have no idea how to do it. I'm also not sure if the code works properly because it should create a dark-gray image but when I open it in SliceDrop it's all black.

Comment: Have a bash with ITK-SNAP as another viewer - also what colormap are you using - if you have only 1 colour in your image then you're going to struggle to map 'light gray' to a  particular color..

Answer (score 0):

Taking cue from [a similar question](https://itk.org/pipermail/insight-users/2010-February/035223.html):

Use [itkEllipseSpatialObject](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1EllipseSpatialObject.html) and [itkSpatialObjectToImageFilter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1SpatialObjectToImageFilter.html).

With `itkEllipseSpatialObject` you can create a sphere of the proper size.
With `itkSpatialObjectToImageFilter` you can rasterize that sphere into a binary image mask.

Both classes should be available via Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces a completely grey volume.  Why would you expect it to create a ball?

Here's code to do it in SimpleITK:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

# create a spherical gaussian blob
gaussian = sitk.GaussianSource(sitk.sitkUInt8,
    size = [100,100,80],
    sigma = [20,20,20],
    mean = [20,20,40],
    spacing = [.4, .4, 1.0])

# threshold to create a binary ball
ball = sitk.BinaryThreshold(gaussian, 150.0, 255.0, 63, 0)

sitk.WriteImage(ball, "ball.nii.gz")
```

If you prefer to stick to ITK, you could do the same thing using the itkGaussianImageSource and itkBinaryThresholdImageFilter classes.